# React - reusable Redux hook slice issue (Redux Toolkit, Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create some hooks to fetch slices of the Redux store so that the store can't access directly to return anything.

If I useSelector directly in the component it works great and doesn't unnecessarily re-render:

```
*** Modal.tsx ***
const { isModalOpen } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.carsSlice); // Works great. No unnecessary re-renders
```

If I create a hook to return the carsSlice then it unnecessarily re-renders the whole page. Why?

E.g.,

```
*** StateHooks.ts ***
const useGlobalState = () => useSelector((state: RootState) => state);
export const useCarsState = () => useGlobalState().carsSlice;

*** Modal.tsx ***
const { isModalOpen } = useCarsState(); // Re-renders underlying page and is significantly slower than above approach
```

I'm fetching the specific value from the state so I don't understand why it would re-render the whole page it is being used on? Is there a way to do this?

I've also tried the below but it still causes page re-render:

```
const useCarsState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.carsSlice); // Same result
```

The only way it works as expected is the below BUT I want the custom hooks above:

```
const { isModalOpen } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.carsSlice); // Works great
```

Thanks all.

Comment: can you share a demo https://codesandbox.io/?
the StateHooks example is not going to work as expected because you are still calling the function that return the entire state. but the last 2 examples should work, so with a working example maybe I could help

Answer (score 1):

you can use [useShallowEqualSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#recipe-useshallowequalselector.)
It will do only rerender when the value from the store is changed.

Moreover, you can put this into a separate hook like:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector, shallowEqual } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "store/rootReducer";

const useShallowEqualSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = (selector) =>
  useSelector(selector, shallowEqual);

export default useShallowEqualSelector;
```

in this case, you are able to use this hook everywhere and you have access to the hints from typescript

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this! Thank you.
I've added this in but it still seems to re-render the page:

export const useGlobalState : TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = selector => useSelector(selector, shallowEqual);

export const useGeneralState = () => useGlobalState((state: RootState) => state.generalSlice); // Is this usage correct?

const { open } = useGeneralState();

Comment: You should use `const open = () => useGlobalState((state: RootState) => state.generalSlice.open)` directly in the component. 

if you would like to use `export const useGeneralState = () => useGlobalState((state: RootState) => state.generalSlice);` you have to look on state in `generalSlice` because in this case you have all properties in `generalSlice` are observable

Answer (score 1):

`useSelector` works by [doing reference comparisons of the value you return](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates).  If that value changes, it forces the component to re-render.

Because of that, **you should never return the entire root state from `useSelector!**  That will cause the component to *always* re-render.

It doesn't matter what additional destructuring you do with the returned value later - what matters is what the selector itself returns.

That's why **you should always select the *smallest* piece of state needed by a given component**, to ensure that it only re-renders when it absolutely needs to because its data actually changed.